# Problem on MYSQL WORKBENCH Connection

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

[image]

Your connection attempt failed for user 'dudu' to the MySQL server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
Acess denied for user 'dudu@'localhost

in linux debian booworm, installed mariadb and mysql

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show your checks that you performed when you followed steps 3 and 4 of the error message.

Answer (score -1):

I see you said you have mysql and mariadb installed.
Mysql-workbench does not connect to mariadb, even though they are somewhat from the same codebase.
Mysql-workbench will only connect to a mysql server.
Mysql-workbench will NOT connect to mariadb server.

Comment: While the answer is probably correct, its best not to ask questions. If in doubt give multiple answers  Downvote is not mine.